# How to detect which pixel format my webcam supports?

Tags: linux, debian, linux-device-driver, v4l2

I am writing a C application that capture video from my webcam.
I am not able to determine which pixel format my webcam is able to process.

**lsusb:**

> Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1e4e:0100 Cubeternet WebCam

**dmesg**

```
[ 1064.735472] usb 2-1.4: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
[ 1064.837577] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=1e4e, idProduct=0100
[ 1064.837583] usb 2-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1064.837587] usb 2-1.4: Product: USB2.0 Camera
[ 1064.837589] usb 2-1.4: Manufacturer: Etron Technologies
[ 1064.837715] usb 2-1.4: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[ 1064.838484] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 Camera (1e4e:0100)
[ 1064.843070] uvcvideo: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
[ 1064.844229] input: USB2.0 Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/input/input7
```

I was able to determine the image size '640x480' but not the pixel format:
I have tried

> YUV420 
>   RGB565
>   RGB32

with no success. Any help Please.
I am using Debian latest version

Comment: Hi Guilherme. I am working on capturing image from a camera sensor. One way to know about color format supported by webcam is to go through the data sheet of the webcam or else default would be raw data. Are you capturing the data outputed from your webcam in a file? If so change the file extension to "file.raw". Download and install "XnView" open source application which will support all the formats.

Comment: @GauthamKantharaju Thanks for your reply. This is a second project that I am developing at night. I´ll check that and I´ll be back to you    . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a UVC video, by looking up the wiki here:

http://www.wikiwand.com/en/USB_video_device_class

You will see that UVC supports

Uncompressed YUV formats YUY2, NV12.

Actually YUY2 is also called YUYV which is YUV 4:2:2.

You can find a conversion to RGB here:

https://bitbucket.org/neuralassembly/simplewebcam/src/a940256eda0d/jni/ImageProc.h

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats
```

That should give you the supported pixel formats

In addition, you can also use:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
```

which should give you the supported pixel formats a resolutions.